# C# JSON without square brackets in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure

I am making an API call which is returning the following:

`{"symbol": "NFLX", "price": 625}`

There are no square brackets incluced.

The following code works only if the response includes square brackets

`[{"symbol": "NFLX", "price": 625}]`

Any idea? I'm guessing it's this line:   `foreach (JToken item in JArray.Parse(apiResponse))`

`

```
                if (apiResponse.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("fs_price");

                        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("symbol", typeof(string)));
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("price", typeof(string)));

                        foreach (JToken item in JArray.Parse(apiResponse))
                        {

                            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                            dataRow["symbol"] = (item["symbol"].ToString() != string.Empty ? item["symbol"] : (object)DBNull.Value);
                            dataRow["price"] = (item["price"].ToString() != string.Empty ? item["price"] : (object)DBNull.Value);

                            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                        }

                        StoreFSData(dataTable);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        erroredOut = true;
                        log.LogError($"Faulted with body: {currentSymbol} and exception: {ex}");
                    }
                }
```

`

Comment: Yes, JArray.Parse is expecting the JSON to be of Array type. You can replace it by JObject.Parse and it will work with `{"symbol": "NFLX", "price": 625}`

Comment: Or you can use JToken.Parse which can parse both Array and Single object.

Comment: Would it be one of these: `JObject item =JObject.Parse(apiResponse);` or 
`JToken item =JObject.Parse(apiResponse);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace `JArray.Parse` with `JObject.Parse`. After my test, it can work for me.

[image]

print:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - 

Having issues setting the datarows, getting a CS0021 error


`dataRow["symbol"] = (item["symbol"].ToString();
dataRow["price"] = (item["price"].ToString()`

Comment: @JesseO  Try to use `dataRow[item.key] = item.value` to test.

Comment: @JesseO  I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Can you accept it as an answer?( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) :)